# Web element not getting recognized randomly

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

**Issue** - Some of the webelements such as Button, textbox and tabs are recognized at times and suddenly stop getting recognized abruptly

> org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up
>   Command duration or timeout: 33.03 seconds

**Code for clicking the button:**

```
Actions actions1 = new Actions(driver);
System.out.println("boolean value of Confirm order is"+driver.findElement(By.id("confirmOrder")).isDisplayed()); ---> Returning True always
WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@id='confirmOrder']")));
System.out.println("Is the Generate order button visible-"+element.isDisplayed());       System.out.println("Is the Generate order button enabled-"+element.isEnabled());
actions1.moveToElement(element);
actions1.click();
actions1.perform();
```

The button `isDisplayed()` always returns true but it gets clicked 1 out of 3 times. This happens with all other elements such as tabs or textboxes. Using Firefox 24 (code is working worst on v25)

Any thoughts as to what's going wrong and why are the elements getting recognized at some time but not all the time?

Comment: your DOM must have been manipulated by javascript, although jquery only might not be the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Use ***Expected Conditions***  and Passing **Control** before performing Click on Any particular **Button**, **Tab** or **Links**

```
         WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 18);
         wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("confirmOrder")));
         WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("confirmOrder"));
            element.sendKeys(org.openqa.selenium.Keys.CONTROL);
            element.click();
```

or you can try with                                                                                                                                                                            **wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("confirmOrder")));**

Answer (score 1):

`StaleElementReferenceException` means that it was pointing to an element, but its changed (either replaced with a similar/identical element, or removed all together).

If your page constantly has active JQuery going on, then there isn't much you can do besides pray for the best.

However, if it simply loading the page with JQuery (and it hasn't finished yet), the following will return true once JQuery is finished:

```
(Boolean)((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return jQuery.active == 0");
```

(I believe the syntax above is correct.  I have abstracted my code away, and so all of the commands may not be exactly right)

Comment: So, does that mean that I need to let the code wait till the jQuery execution gets over by using the above code you posted?

Comment: Yes.  I would put that command in a while loop.  (Probably with a timeout as well).